# Extra entry in ARP table?

Tags: arp

I am new to networking so please have mercy on my noob soul...

I hope this question is acceptable for this forum.  It just got kicked out of the networkengineering.stackexchange.com forum, so I'm trying to repost it here.  Here goes...

I am running a Windows 10 Pro x64 box, and when I run "arp -a" or when I look at my network connections using XArp, I see what I think is an extra entry in my ARP table. I only have one computer hooked up to the current Wi-Fi network that I am using to connect to the internet but in both tools, I see an extra ARP entry with an ip address on my local network that I do not think should be there. Since the XArp entry gives the most info, I will duplicate it here. I see the below entry when I don't think it should be there:

```
IP            MAC                Host          Vendor        Interface        Online   Cache 
192.168.0.10  00-18-4d-ff-ff-07  192.168.0.10  Netgear Inc.  0x-10 Microsoft  unknown  yes

First Seen           Last Seen            How often seen
9/17/2021 14:59:35   9/17/2021 14:59:35   1
```

In addition, the readout from running the "arp -a" command on my Windows box indicates that the above arp table entry is dynamic.

This entry has only been seen once because I actually deleted the entry with an "arp -d 192.168.0.10" command. It then returned upon a restart of my XArp screen.

I have been worried that someone is messing around with my network and somehow logging onto it and doing who knows what else without my permission.

(I do not recognize the above 00-18-4d-ff-ff-07 MAC address as any MAC address I can find anywhere on my machine. Again, my machine should be the only machine connected to the Wi-Fi network I am using to connect to the internet. And again, this extra ip address seems to be local to this Wi-Fi network that I think should only have my local machine connected to it.

The ip address for my local machine is 192.168.0.14, and its MAC address matches the one that shows in the Properties page for the Wi-Fi network I am connected to on this machine.)

Is this "extra entry" in my ARP table evidence that someone other than myself is logged onto my network?

Or is this entry just something that my Netgear router is doing?

(FWIW, the MAC address for my Netgear router at the ip address 192.168.0.1 is totally different from the MAC address for the 192.168.0.10 ip address shown above, and the MAC address for my router at the 192.168.0.1 ip address matches up well with the MAC address on the sticker/label on my router.)

Thanks in advance for any help with this question.

Comment: That's your system's ARP table. You will never see any entries that match your own system, only addresses belonging to other devices in the network. Your NetGear router has at least 2 MAC addresses - every single port and Wi-Fi antenna needs its own. Put 192.168.0.10 to your browser - do you get to the router's login page? What's the router model?

Comment: When I put 192.168.0.10 into the browser address bar, I do not get the router login page.  I use Firefox as my browser, and I get a page saying that Firefox was "Unable to connect.  Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 192.168.0.10."  My cable-modem/router is a Netgear Nighthawk AC1900 WiFi Cable Modem Router:  Model C7000v2.

Comment: Also, the info I posted came from the XArp tool.  This tool does show information about the connection from my local machine.  Output from XArp is slightly different from the output you get when you run "arp -a" from a command prompt in Windows.

Comment: You should be able to log into your router and get the list of devices it has given out addresses to.  If the mystery address is coming from the router itself, it should be listed somewhere in the router's configuration if it isn't in the device table.

Comment: G'morning :) The router has 3 antennas & 5 ports = 8 MAC addresses. I installed XArp yestereve and noticed that it indeed shows also my own NIC - I think this is to check if user's own system is being used as attacker. it seems to do active polling. The detection above is registered by your wired NIC. Do you connect to your router with cable or wirelessly?

Comment: I am connecting to my router via Wi Fi.  How do you know that the above ip address and mac address is registered as a wired address?  Nothing is connected to my router via a wired connection.

Comment: Nothing on my end is connected to my router via a wired connection, at least.  In the past, when I saw suspicious activity on my router, I also saw wired connections that at that time mimicked the mac address for my wireless connection.  An attacker would have had to mimic my wireless address to connect at the time because I was using Access Control that only allowed certain mac addresses to connect.  I don't have Access Control turned on now, though.  If someone knew the mac address for my router, could they connect to it via a wired connection?  What could they do if they were able to do so?

Comment: For example, I am hesitant to log in to my router with it connected to the internet.  In most cases, I disconnect the internet and log in to my router with a wired connection when I log in to my router.  I do this to make sure that no one on the internet can sniff my router login password.  Is this sort of sniffing something that someone could do if indeed they are logged in to my router via a wired connection (because they know the mac address of my router) when I login to my router, provided that I don't disconnect my router from the internet when I log in to it?

Comment: Hang on a sec :-D I'll be with you in a few. You're not in immediate danger :-)

Comment: Certainly @Peregrino69... take your time.  I definitely appreciate all the help you are giving me!!

Comment: I just need to let XArp run for a while to get a proper screenshot :-) ... and my Windows system decided to install some updates just now...

Comment: OK that took time... I hope it's understandable. The most important part is at the end; "To allow maximum security".

Answer (score 0):

Here's XArp output from my test system:

[image: XArp output]

Virtuows is the Windows system, TREX the internet gateway. As you can see, XArp shows 2 interfaces, 0x8 is the Wi-Fi adapter, 0x10 is wired. Your 192.168.0.10 is associated with interface 0x10 - i.e. it was "detected" by the wired interface.

arp -a identifies the interfaces the same way:

[image: arp -a output]

This shows what *actually* is present in the network. The only detected device is 192.168.122.1, the internet gateway. .255 is the broadcast address of the network, 224- and 239-addresses are reserved multicast addresses; these (and manually configured entries) are always static. Otherwise ARP table entries are dynamic, they age out and disappear in a few minutes if not re-detected.

XArp documentation is woefully inadequate. I don't know how exactly it works, so I can't explain for certain where the .0.10 -address comes from. However if XArp sees it once, it's can't be an active device in the network. Active devices always exchange ARP-, Hello- and other similar packets; the systems need to know who's actually present in the network to keep connections open. It seems to originate from the router, but to be certain you'd need to do a traffic trace, and that's useful *only* if there are more than a single detection.

Check the settings of your wired adapter - does it have a static IP? If yes, change that to DHCP. You can give commands `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` to renew all existing DHCP leases in your system. If the .0.10 -address is lurking somewhere there, this'll flush it out.

What comes to XArp - I don't think you should bother with it. Notice that in my system it shows multiple "attack" detections, all originating from my own Wi-Fi adapter which isn't even connected anywhere - am I a danger to myself?

In the hands of a knowledgeable netadmin it could be a useful tool, but for an average user in home setting it's pretty much useless. The language used in the webpage can sound scary to the uninitiated, but it's exaggerated and in parts just dead wrong. If you want to see what actually is out there, your router's management interface is your best friend. Arp -a output might be but due to the nature of arp protocol it's a bit limited.

> when I saw suspicious activity on my router, I also saw wired connections that at that time mimicked the mac address for my wireless connection.

I don't know how you determine activity to be "suspicious". If a network interface has an active connection, the LEDs will always be blinking fast and randomly - that only means traffic's passing through that interface. You can see wired connection only when an actual device is connected to your router port. Or if the device firmware has a bug. But just knowing the MAC address your router is not sufficient.

> If someone knew the mac address for my router, could they connect to it via a wired connection?

No, that's only possible by plugging in an actual cable.

> I am hesitant to log in to my router with it connected to the internet. In most cases, I disconnect the internet and log in to my router with a wired connection when I log in to my router. I do this to make sure that no one on the internet can sniff my router login password.

By default all SoHo routers allow management *only* through the LAN interface, you have to actually configure it to be managed over the internet; it might be impossible altogether. The username/password is anyway only passed between your device and the router, never sent out of the internet port. The router also contains a firewall which by default blocks all incoming traffic.

To ensure maximum security:

1. Firewall configuration is explained in [the manual](https://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/R7000/R7000_UM.pdf) page 65 and 66. Don't disable PortScan and DoS protection, don't configure DMZ server. Don't allow respond to ping on internet port. Keep SIP ALG and IGMP proxying disabled. If you're not a gamer you don't have to enable NAT filtering either.
2. Use only WPA2-PSK with a complicated Wi-Fi password you can easily remember. One good way is to choose a short sentece and mangle it a bit. For (a bad) example "this gives access to internet" could be mangled to "Th159iv3s@ccEs5-70Int#rn37".
3. Don't enable Guest networks
4. Enable Access Control, and only allow your own device's MAC address
5. The manual suggests that the defult IP address range is 192.168.1.0/24, but yours seems to be 192.168.0.0/24. In any case, both of these are very common, so you can change it to something more rarely used like 192.168.47.0/24. Don't change anything else but the third octet! This makes it a bit more difficult to guess.

These are pretty much sufficient for an average user. There are also some further steps you could take:

- If you use your computer only at home, you could configure it with a static IP address and disable DHCP on the router
- You can prevent the SSID from being broadcast, so your network isn't visible for everyone

I wouldn't bother with these, as they don't really add that much to the security. A moderately knowledgeable person can overcome each of these pretty easily. But then again a dedicated, highly skilled person with enough time can bypass just about any security measure in existence.

Security is always a bit of a balancing game. How tightly do I want to close things down vs. how much trouble do I want to have in everyday usage. The best protection is knowledge. There's also the human aspect - skilled hackers target government / military organizations, banks, insurance companies and other such - how interesting would a random person's home network be for them? :-)

---

Just in case one of XArp developers sees this and takes an issue: ***I'm in no way shape or form dissing your tool.*** I'm merely pointing out that understanding what it shows and how it can be used requires knowledge far beyond the ken of an average user.

Comment: When I saw "suspicious activity", I was logged in to my router via Wi Fi at the time (with it connected to the internet), and I saw a wired connection that used my then-current Wi Fi mac address log on to my router (while I was also logged in).  I was in the room with my router at the time, and nothing was plugged into my router with an ethernet cable.  My machine was the only one connected to the internet (via Wi Fi) from my end.  Someone was able to bypass Access Control on my router by spoofing my (allowed) Wi Fi mac address and also spoofing a wired connnection to the router.

Comment: So, someone has the ability to spoof a wired connection to this router.  I'm pretty sure that the 00-18-4d-ff-ff-07 mac address is showing up as a wired connection to my router in its settings pages.  I recall now that I had seen this before I turned on Access Control in the past.  Then, after I turned on Access Control in the router, the attacker just spoofed my Wi Fi mac address and spoofed another wired connection to my router to logon to my router as described in the above comment.

Comment: Also, the 192.168.0.10 ip address is showing up in my "arp -a" output as well as in my XArp output.  This ip address showing up is not some artefact of XArp.  In addition, it currently shows 5 connections over the last hour or so in my XArp client.  It only showed 1 connection in my previous post because I ran XArp immediately after deleting it  with an "arp -d 192.168.0.10" command.  So the 192.168.0.10 ip address does seem to be a real external machine connected to my router that is spoofing its connection as a wired connection.

Comment: I know the directions for comments advise me to avoid giving "Thanks" out, but I want to thank you for all your help anyway!!  I do appreciate all your help, for sure.

Comment: If the solution works, accepting is enough :-D Also if something is unclear please do feel free to ask - I will get a notification of comments here. Besides I learned of a new tool; I've never even heard about XArp before :-)

Comment: The solution doesn't work, unfortunately.  I have already followed all of your suggestions in the past, but as I said in the comments above, that did not stop my attacker from being able to connect to the internet through my router.  (In an above comment I indicated that the attacker logged on to my router.  I misspoke in this instance.  I only ever saw evidence that the attacker connected to the internet through my router.)  I will try turning on Access Control again, though.  My Wi Fi password is already more secure than you suggest, etc...

Comment: Oh, my bad. I hope you don't think I'm making light of you! Unfortunately I can't say anything about someone logging into your router or accessing internet through it, I'd need to see the evidence myself. I'd love to sit down with you for half an hour and see exactly what's what, but... do you suspect something strange is going on right now?